# Outputting and Inputting audio from two headsets on OSX 10.6

Tags: macos, audio, skype, headset

Is there any software or tool that will allow me to use two headsets (both logitech), effectively as one device? Both work on their own, and I tried creating an aggregate device, but when I try to *use* the aggregate device, I can't adjust volume, and neither headset seems to get output.

Is there a better way to do this, or some software that makes this easier?

Comment: How do you connect both? Are these USB headsets?

Answer (score 0):

[Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/) can do this. It is free/open source software.

Comment: I don't see how. This only lets me route input to outpout, it seems, not take input from two headsets and set output to two headsets.